# linter swears on the lack of properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

When calling a component in which there is a 'connect' from 'redux' and properties that need to be transferred when calling, the linter swears at the absence of properties

Component1

```
interface Component1Props {
   id: numbers;
   users: any[];
}

const Component1: React.FC<Component1Props> = ({
  id,
  users
}) => {
  ...
};


const mapStateToProps = ({ users }: any) => ({
  users
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Component1);
```

Component2

```
import Component1 from ...

const Component2 = () => {
  return <Component1 id={id} />; <-- linter error: property 'users' is missing
}
```

How fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use this approach from their official document

[typing-the-connect-higher-order-component](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript/#typing-the-connect-higher-order-component)

**ConnectedProps**

> Use the `ConnectedProps<T>` type exported by `@types/react-redux^7.1.2` to infer the types of the props from `connect` automatically.

```
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux'

interface RootState {
}
const mapState = (state: RootState) => ({
})
const mapDispatch = {
}
const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch)

type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>
type Props = PropsFromRedux & {
  backgroundColor: string
}

const MyComponent = (props: Props) => (
  <div style={{ backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor }}>
    <button onClick={props.toggleOn}>
      Toggle is {props.isOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
    </button>
  </div>
)
export default connector(MyComponent)
```